# What is the next step to take when receiving this mysqldiff error?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that has been in production and saved and restored  a few times with phpmyadmin and mysqldump/restore.
I suspect the "production activity" has introduced some discrepancies  between this DB structure and any new "pristine" database that was created from the original schema defining SQL.

when I try to compare the production DB against a brand new instance, using `mysqldiff`, I get:

```
$ mysqldiff --server1=root@localhost dev_si_brand_new:prod_si
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Comparing `dev_si_brand_new` to `prod_si`                        [FAIL]
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `dev_si_brand_new`
+++ `prod_si`
@@ -1 +1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `dev_si_brand_new` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
+CREATE DATABASE `prod_si` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
Compare failed. One or more differences found.
```

From the [mysqldiff documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldiff.html)

> When a database pair is specified, all objects in one database are compared to the corresponding objects in the other. Any objects not appearing in either database produce an error.

Is it possible to get debug info?
What do I need to do to generate a useful diff report?

Note: I am running

- `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43`
- Ubuntu linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqldiff` is just telling you that you have a difference between both DB, regarding the DB name : `dev_si_brand_new` versus `prod_si`.

If you don't want `mysqldiff` stops at the first difference encountered and continue the comparison, just add the `--force` argument to your command line :

> --force
>
> Do not halt at the first difference found. Process all objects to find
>   all differences.

```
mysqldiff --force --server1=root@localhost dev_si_brand_new:prod_si
```

Comment: thanks, working now! any idea what the reasoning is behind having to use `--force` to override "error"s on a comparison where you are *expecting* to get differences?

Comment: You don't have to consider it as an error, but more like a "difference found" failure. `mysqldiff ` is designed to report a failure when it encounters a difference, and stops by default at the first difference found, considering it should be corrected immediately. This is why the `--force` exists. IMHO, the reason behind that is mainly in case of a new developpement has to be applied in a live environnement. Once applied on the live environnement, using `mysqldiff` to compare live versus dev environnement should report OK if the update ran fine.

Comment: makes sense, I could see how it would be helpful to locate and incrementally fix differences due to `mysqldiff` exiting on difference,  but  when you consider the 2 databases **have** to have different names when hosted on the same server. so  you are always going to have to run `--force` (except when comparing across servers) so you are not going to get the "exit when difference found" benefit. but anyway, I have a list of diffs so I can continue patching anyway, thanks

Comment: Note that you also have the `--sql` argument that will generate the SQL code for you to make both equal, regarding the difference found.

Comment: `--sql` produces `mysqldiff: error: no such option: --sql` on my version of `mysqldiff version 1.3.5`.  The command line output and the docs I linked to in my question say to use `--changes-for=server1` : *Produce output that shows how to make the definitions of objects on server1 like the definitions of the corresponding objects on server2.* just tested this now and its produced SQL successfully

Comment: You are absolutely right, and your method is best. By the way, the argument i was talking about was `--difftype=sql` (typo). But keep using `--changes-for` :)